# CruiseControl.NET SVN Re-location Problem

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net, visualsvn

I currently have CruiseControl.NET set up with SVN to automatically grab the code source from the repository. After having a problem with our SVN server - I recreated a different SVN location for it and changed the location of it in the ccnet.config file. This caused problems with CruiseControl.NET still trying to grab it from the old SVN repository.

I have tried restarting the CruiseControl.NET service, deleting artifacts and any other files related to the project and changing the project name but it still tries to grab the code from the wrong SVN location.

The error I'm getting is this:

```
    ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Source control operation
     failed: 
     svn: OPTIONS of 'http://local.oldsvnserver/svn/OldRepository': authorization      
     failed (local.oldsvnserver). 

     Process command: C:/Program Files (x86)/Subversion/svn.exe update --username username--password password --non-interactive --no-auth-cache at 
     ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.ProcessSourceControl.Execute(ProcessInfo processInfo) at 
     ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Svn.GetSource(IIntegrationResult result) at 
     ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Build(IIntegrationResult result)
```

where the new sourcecontrol block is:

```
<sourcecontrol type="svn">
  <executable>C:/Program Files (x86)/Subversion/svn.exe</executable>
  <trunkUrl>http://local.newsvnswever/svn/SiteRepository/</trunkUrl>
  <username>username</username>
  <password>password</password>
  <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
  <workingDirectory></workingDirectory>
</sourcecontrol>
```

Any help would be awesome,

ChrisNTR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Stop CCNet
2. Verify that there are no references to your old repository location in ccnet.config
3. Blow away the state files for your projects.  The files are called PROJECTNAME.state.
4. Blow away the working directories for your projects.
5. Restart the machine (which I am assuming will restart the CCNet service).

That should clean out just about everything and should eliminate old stuff in CCNet as the source of the issue.

Comment: Managed to get it working - I didn't have to restart the server - just manually stopped and started the services. I thought I had done this already but gave it another shot. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

"authorization failed" means that the **authentication** was successful (i.e., the user is known) but that the user doesn't have access (i.e. the user is not **authorized**) to that repository folder (or the whole repository).

Check your svn server configuration.

Comment: Stefan, This isn't the problem I'm facing - sorry it isn't clear. I'm moving away from the SVN server it's trying to authenticate with and use a different one however it's still trying to go the old one above.